# Does std::cout has a maximum size to hold character?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int b = 3;
    int* a;
    *a = b;

    std::cout << &a << a << *a;
}
```

When I execute *a.out*, **Segmentation fault** occurs

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int b = 3;
    int* a;
    *a = b;

    std::cout << &a << a;
    std::cout << *a;
}
```

While this code runs clearly with no error.

I'm pretty sure that max size of `stdout` buffer is bigger than couple of characters...

Why am I seeing **Segmentation fault** in same code with different new line?

Comment: You have UB in `*a=b` already.

Comment: Because the pointer `a` is uninitialized and points to anywhere (or nowhere). This is U.B. as soon as you access the contents/reference by `*a`.

Comment: Instead, you might have done `a = &b;`. Then `a` would point to the storage of `b` and would be defined.

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I seeing Segmentation fault ...?

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined. Here is the list of bugs in your programs:

> ```
> *a = b;
> ^^
> indirect through indeterminate pointer
> ```

> ```
> std::cout << &a << a << *a;
>                    ^    ^^
>                    |    indirect through indeterminate pointer
>                    read an indeterminate value
> ```

These bugs affect both example programs.

To fix the bugs, initialise `a` with a valid address of an `int` object.